# changing Permalink to Post name breaks creating pages, (field to publish)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, debian, linode

I just created a new linode wordpress installation and everything is working right, but when i change the settings for the Permalinks in wordpress to Post name instead of plain, creating new pages and posts breaks. when I try to create a new page it returns field to publish.

All I'm trying to do is to change the link for home and about pages to something like `http://example.com/home.php` and `http://example.com/about.php` instead of this crazy thing `http://example.com/home.php?page=2/post=23`

Comment: (Why would you want a `.php` suffix for pages created by WordPress in the first place?) Do you have the .htaccess set up properly? Does the hosting account allow you to use mod_rewrite for URL rewriting?

Comment: I don't care about the suffix, my problem is that I want the url to  have the page name instead of this `home.php?page=2/post=23` thing. I did `chmod 777 /var/www/wordpress/.htaccess` yet it's still the same

Comment: also forgot to mention. it's default linod one click wordpress image